# How do you resolve "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Non-1D inputs to pie() are currently squeeze()d"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you resolve "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Non-1D inputs to pie() are currently squeeze()d"? 
Non 1-D inputs?
All inputs are 1-D lists or percentage values.

```
plt.pie(values,labels=subjects,colors=cols,autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `values` are, but most likely a n-D array. If so, you can do:

```
plt.pie(np.array(values).ravel(),labels=subjects,colors=cols,autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Comment: @LyraOrwell can you try wrapping `values` around `np.array` to see if it works?